# Symfony2, Security, registration and isEnable error

Tags: security, symfony, login-control

Guys there is a description about how to make 'isEnabled' (active\inactive account) on registration.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#forbid-inactive-users

But there is NO description how to get this error on login action. For example I have working properly registration where user account default is inactive. After user login how can I get "inAcitve" if account is not activated by email link?

Comment: Have you tried the FOSUserBundle https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle ? It is designed to handle common tasks like registering and email-confirming.

Comment: No, i'm not interesting in standalone bundles, I want to know how can I do this in native SF2.

Answer (score 0):

Is pretty easy: you can create a service that will act as a event listener

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
  your_bundle_name.login_listener:
    class: FQN\Of\Your\Bundle\Class\Listener
    tags: 
      - { kernel.event_listener, security.interactive_login}
```

tags part is there because, on bootstrap of your application, kernel will "attach" certain type of events to your service and will call a method on that service each time this event is raised.
So `kernel.event_listener` is there because every event listener have to be tagged that way (follow it as a "rule") and `security.interactive_login` will be fired as a user succesfully log in.

Your class could be something like

```
//omitting class declaration on purpose
public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event) {
  $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
  if (!$user->isActive()) {
    //do the proper action to display the error
  }
}
```